# orderByChild and startAt firebase realtime using Date timestamp not returning data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
- foo
|--- -LK7rNAPKZP7drHK1eb_
      |- timeStamp: 1534966072658
|--- -LKAPfu2lLl2B5zInIhX
      |- timeStamp: 1534965117552
|--- -LKJN97VxOhnE8XoNSQN
      |- timeStamp: 1534946072623

db.ref('foo').orderByChild('timeStamp').startAt(Date.now().toString()).limitToLast(7).once('value', data => {
    console.log(data.val());
}
```

The result is null. When I don't put the .startAt I am able to get data and it actually is sorted by timestamp... However, I need to be able to set the startAt since I am doing an infinite scrolling and I need to be able to specify the last timeStamp record.  What am I doing wrong? I want to pull the first 7 records

Using firebase realtime db

Answer (score 1):

In short, don't call `toString()` on `Date.now()`, just leave it as a number.

---

From [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order):

> 4: Children with a numeric value come next, sorted in ascending order. If
>   multiple children have the same numerical value for the specified
>   child node, they are sorted by key.
>
> 5: Strings come after numbers and are
>   sorted lexicographically in ascending order. If multiple children have
>   the same value for the specified child node, they are ordered
>   lexicographically by key.

As you can see, string values are always sorted after numbers, so by specifying a string on your `startAt`, you have guaranteed that no entry with a numeric value for that field will be in the result. Since all your entries are numeric, that means your result is `null`.

Comment: I tried using the Date timestamp without .toString() but was getting warning saying that it needed to be string format. When I put with normal number date object timestamp from Date.now() it also returns null from firebase

Comment: Where do you see this warning? If you can you edit it into your post I'll see if I can figure why it's showing up. But aside from the warning, does using the date as a plain number return the correct results from your DB?

Comment: I'm actually no longer getting any error/msg, I am just getting a null object returned.... nothign is coming back

Comment: What is crazy... if I only use .orderByChild('timeStamp') the data comes back and it is sorted. However, I need to ahve access to .startAt() ... I need to be able to specify the timestamp that I want to return the result query from. That is where the problem is... startAt(Date.now()) .

Comment: It looks like you want the most recent 7 records? In that case, you might try using `.endAt` instead of `.startAt`. Using `startAt(Date.now())` will only pull records with a timestamp that is in the future.

Comment: I think .endAt might do it... let me keep playing

Comment: CRice, i think i am good now... all day i was using the .startAt and it was acting funky. Now i switched to endAt and can use the Date.now and its working. Will keep testing. thx